# Existence of normal subgroup of group with given property

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

> Let G be a finite group in which $(ab)^p=a^pb^p$ for every a,b in G where p is prime dividing order of G
>   Then if P is p- Sylow subgroup of G then there exists a normal subgroup N of G with $P\cap N=e $ and PN=G.

I PROVED that P is normal. But unable to proceed further .any hint will be useful

Comment: Would you share how you proved that $P$ is normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the set of $p$-th powers in $G$, they form a subgroup because $a^pb^p=(ab)^p$, and is clearly characteristic.  Moreover, it is a proper subgroup of $G$ by cardinality, so let $N_1$ be this characteristic subgroup.  We claim $N_1P=G$ (easy).

Unfortunately $N_1\cap P$ need not be trivial, so look at the characteristic subgroup $N_2$ of $p$-th powers in $N_1$ as needed, repeat.  Since the exponent of $P$ is at most $\lvert P\rvert$, this process stops with an $N$ that works.

In fact, it is easy to see that we have
$$N=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\phi^n(G)\text{ and }P=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\ker(\phi^n),$$
where $\phi\colon G\to G$ is the homomorphism $g\mapsto g^p$.

Comment: Nice answer. I had trouble to show N1 is characteristic.i understand that it contains all element of G other than element of order p.I know that if unique order subgroup then it is characteristics.but how to show this unique?

Comment: $N_1$ is the set of $p$-th powers of elements of $G$, and that is unchanged under all automorphisms of $G$ ($\psi\in\operatorname{Aut}G$ map $g^p$ to.$\psi(g)^p$, or $(g\psi)^p$ if you want).

Comment: @user10354138 How do you prove that in fact $N \cap P=1$?

Answer (score 0):

An observation in a different direction: let $\phi: G \rightarrow G$ be defined by $\phi(g)=g^p$. Then $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and put $p^e=exp(P)$, the smallest power of $p$ such that $x^{p^e}=1$ for all $x \in Syl_p(G)$. Observe that $\phi^e$ is a homomorphism, since it is an iteration of mappings ($\phi^e(g)=\phi(\phi(\phi \cdots (g) \cdots))$, $e$ times). Note that $P \subseteq ker(\phi^e)$. On the other hand, $ker(\phi^e)$ is a $p$-subgroup. We conclude that $P=ker(\phi^e)$ and hence $P$ is normal. Now we can use the theorem of [Schur-Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem) to provide a complement subgroup $H$ to $P$: $G=HP$ and $H \cap P=1$.